# How do I hide a specific point in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I would like to make it so that in this code, after you draw a new line, then the old one will disappear after 2 seconds, and during these 2 seconds, you cannot draw any more lines. I am confused as to why my code right now is not working. Basically, I am trying to use tick and a variable to tell me when 2 seconds have elapsed, but for some reason, it does do anything.

```
from pygame import * 

init()
size = width, height = 650, 650
screen = display.set_mode(size)

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 100, 94)
BLUE = (112, 219, 255)
GREEN = (138, 255, 142)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 158)
color = GREEN

running = True
myClock = time.Clock()
prevprev_pos = None
prev_pos = None
cur_pos = None
start_time = None

# Game Loop
while running:
    for e in event.get(): 
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            if e.button == 1:                
                if cur_pos != None and prev_pos == None:  #if clicked once and not twice
                    start_time = time.get_ticks()
                    prevprev_pos = prev_pos
                    prev_pos = cur_pos
                    cur_pos = e.pos
                if prev_pos == None: #if not clicked twice 
                    cur_pos = e.pos 


            if e.button == 3:      
                if color == GREEN:
                    color = BLUE
                elif color == BLUE:
                    color = RED
                elif color == RED:
                    color = GREEN                     

    if prev_pos != None:   #when clicked twice, draw line
        if time.get_ticks() - start_time <= 2000:
            screen.fill(BLACK)
            draw.line(screen, color, prevprev_pos, prev_pos)
            draw.line(screen, color, prev_pos, cur_pos)
            draw.circle(screen, color, prev_pos, 5) 


        else:   #after 2 seconds, reset pos of clicks, and clear screen
            prev_pos = None
            cur_pos = None
            screen.fill(BLACK)


    if cur_pos != None:   #if clicked once, draw the circle
        draw.circle(screen, color, cur_pos, 5)

    display.flip()
    myClock.tick(60)

quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only checking for the 2 seconds when you click, you need it to check every frame. Moving the `if prev_pos != None:` out of the event loop and changing `e.pos` to `cur_pos` seemed to almost get what you were after. After adding a bit here and there, i think i got what you were after

```py
from pygame import * 

init()
size = width, height = 650, 650
screen = display.set_mode(size)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 100, 94)
BLUE = (112, 219, 255)
GREEN = (138, 255, 142)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 158)
color = GREEN

running = True
myClock = time.Clock()
prev_pos = None
cur_pos = None
start_time = None

# Game Loop
while running:
    for e in event.get(): 
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if e.button == 1:              
                if cur_pos != None and prev_pos == None:  #if clicked once and not twice
                    start_time = time.get_ticks()
                    prev_pos = cur_pos
                    print("start")
                    cur_pos = e.pos
                if prev_pos == None: #if not clicked twice
                    cur_pos = e.pos                 

            if e.button == 3:      
                if color == GREEN:
                    color = BLUE
                elif color == BLUE:
                    color = RED
                elif color == RED:
                    color = GREEN

    if prev_pos != None:   #when clicked twice, draw line
        if time.get_ticks() - start_time <= 2000:
            screen.fill(BLACK)
            draw.line(screen, color, prev_pos, cur_pos)
            draw.circle(screen, color, prev_pos, 5) 
        else:   #after 2 seconds, reset pos of clicks, and clear screen
            prev_pos = None
            cur_pos = None
            screen.fill(BLACK)

    if cur_pos != None:   #if clicked once, draw the circle
        draw.circle(screen, color, cur_pos, 5)

    display.flip()
    myClock.tick(60)

quit()
```

---

```
                if prev_pos != None and prev_prev_pos == None:
                    start_time = time.get_ticks()
                    prev_pos = cur_pos
                    print("start")
                    cur_pos = e.pos
                if cur_pos != None and prev_pos == None:
                    prev_pos = cur_pos
                if prev__prev_pos == None:
                    cur_pos = e.pos
```

and

```
if prev_prev_pos != None:   
        if time.get_ticks() - start_time <= 2000:
            screen.fill(BLACK)
            draw.line(screen, color, prev_pos, cur_pos)
            draw.circle(screen, color, prev_pos, 5) 
            draw.circle(...)
        else:
            prev_pos = None
            prev_prev_pos = None
            cur_pos = None
            screen.fill(BLACK)
```

---

```py
from pygame import * 

init()
size = width, height = 650, 650
screen = display.set_mode(size)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 100, 94)
BLUE = (112, 219, 255)
GREEN = (138, 255, 142)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 158)
color = GREEN

running = True
myClock = time.Clock()

start_time = None


points = [] 
times = []
max_lines = 2

# Game Loop
while running:

    screen.fill(BLACK)  #clear the screen

    for e in event.get(): 
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if e.button == 1:              
                if len(points) < max_lines + 1: #if not max lines on screen
                    if len(points) > 0: #if there is already a point in list, move all across and add new pos to start
                        times.append(time.get_ticks())  
                        points.append(points[-1])
                        for i in range(len(points)-2,-1,-1):
                            points[i] = points[i - 1]
                        points[0] = mouse.get_pos()                        
                    else:  #else append first point
                        points.append(mouse.get_pos())
            if e.button == 3:      
                if color == GREEN:
                    color = BLUE
                elif color == BLUE:
                    color = RED
                elif color == RED:
                    color = GREEN

    for i in range(len(points)-1,-1,-1): #for every point in points
        draw.circle(screen,color,points[i],5)
        if i < len(points) - 1:  #after second point, draw lines
            draw.line(screen,color,points[i],points[i+1])
            if time.get_ticks() - times[i - 1] > 2000:  #check for  seconds
                del points[i + 1]    #delete last point
                del times[i - 1]    #delete the time

    display.flip()
    myClock.tick(60)

quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your hard work, this is extremely helpful. I was thinking of being able to draw 2 line segments instead of just 1. Where in the code can I change this?

Comment: @conyieie Also need if prev pos draw circle. This is if they are connected.

Comment: I made some edits, can you tell me why my new variable (prevprev_pos) isn't working? I just want to store the previous point so I can make another line and save the old one, but for some reason, the starting point isn't valid.

Comment: @conyieie Yeah, this is where it can start to get complicated, in your code, when you click, the `if cur_pos != None and prev_pos == None:` means if cur_pos = something, so clicked once, and prev_pos == nothing, so not clicked twice, your then trying to assign prev_pos tp prevprev_pos, bit prev_pos = nothing so prevprev_pos = nothing. you will need a new if statement like in my example for if clicked twice but not 3 times. a `if prev_pos != None and prev_prev_pos == None:`

Comment: also, is there a way to NOT reset everything at the end? I want for the new line I draw to continue from the old one, but being as all the if statements compare these variables to None, I don't think this is possible. Should I just restart my code?

Comment: @conyieie It definately isnt the best way to do it, so if its not exactly what your after, mabye yeah, you could try to use a list and maybe an int for how many points are allready on the screen.

Comment: @conyieie Sorry to kill your fun but i made it using lists and stores the last point so you can keep going, i made a `max_lines` so you can adjust if wanted