# How to use time.get_tick()

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, pygame

When I left click, a line should show from the origin, and if left clicked with two seconds, white circles should appear. After two seconds, another line is drawn and then after two seconds the previous line should disappear. Right now, when I click, a line shows from the origin and then when I click again, two lines show.

```
from pygame import *
import random

init()
size = width, height = 700, 700
screen = display.set_mode(size)
button = 0

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
color = RED

mx = 0
my = 0
cx = 0
cy = 0


def drawScene(screen, button):
  if button == 1:
    draw.circle(screen, RED, (mx,my), 5)
    draw.line(screen, color, (mx,my),(lx,ly), 2)
    cx = lx
    cy = ly   
    draw.circle(screen, RED, (mx,my), 5)

    display.flip()
  if button == 3:
    draw.line(screen, color, (mx,my),(lx,ly), 2)
    draw.circle(screen, color, (lx,ly), 5)

    display.flip()


running = True
myClock = time.Clock()


# Game Loop
while running:
  lx = mx
  ly = my


  for evnt in event.get():             # checks all events that happen
    if evnt.type == QUIT:
      running = False

    if evnt.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      mx,my = evnt.pos
      button = evnt.button

      if time.get_ticks() <= 2000 and time.get_ticks() > 0 :
        draw.circle(screen, WHITE, (mx,my), 5)
      else:
        draw.line(screen, WHITE, (cx,cy),(lx,ly), 2)

      if button == 3:
        if  color == RED:
          color = BLUE
        elif color == BLUE:
          color = GREEN
        elif color == GREEN:
          color = RED


  drawScene(screen, button)

  myClock.tick(60) 

quit()
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to do, when you click, a line should appear from the origin to the mouse without circles? then if you click within 2 seconds of last click, you want circles to show, at where? then after 2 seconds you want another line to draw, from the last 2 points clicked? then after another 2 seconds, you want the original line to disappear? you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61672673/11474874)

Comment: yes that is exactly what I need. the circles should up where you clicked

Comment: does the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61672673/11474874) from the other question help or do you want me to go through it

Comment: the answer from the other question was confusing. Can you please go through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with setting up a basic window first

```py
from pygame import *
import random

init()
size = width, height = 700, 700
screen = display.set_mode(size)
button = 0

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
color = RED
running = True
myClock = time.Clock()


def drawScene():
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    display.update() #update is the same as flip()

# Game Loop
while running:
    myClock.tick(60)
    drawScene()


    for evnt in event.get():             # checks all events that happen
        if evnt.type == QUIT:
            running = False
```

After helping someone else with this problem (the question i linked), i found that using lists would be the best idea

So lets create a list for the points where the circles go and lines connect to

```
points = [] #put this before the drawScene function so it can reference it
```

Now, when the user clicks, we want to add the point to the list and draw it on the screen

```py
def drawScene():
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    for point in points:
        draw.circle(screen,color,point,5)

    display.update() #update is the same as flip()
```

```py
if evnt.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    points.append(evnt.pos)
```

now we can create points on the screen by clicking. Lets create the lines

We want to start at the origin so add the origin to the list at the start

```
points = [(0,0)]
```

Now we want to loop through every point and draw a circle and a line in between. so change the loop to

```py
for i in range(1,len(points)): #loop through all but the first point as you dont want circle at origin
        draw.circle(screen,WHITE,points[i],5)
        draw.line(screen,color,points[i - 1],points[i])
```

Now we can draw lines and circles. But we only want to draw the circles if we clicked within 2 seconds, so lets create a timer, we will make one for each line so lets make a list as each line disappears after 2 seconds aswell

```
timers = []
```

Once we click, we want to start the timer, we can do that with

```py
if evnt.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    points.append(evnt.pos)
    timers.append(time.get_ticks())
```

this gets the current time in milliseconds we want to know once its been 2 seconds so if we get the current time and minus the start time, we get the difference so

```
for i in range(len(timers)-1,-1,-1):
    if time.get_ticks() - timers[i] > 2000: #if been 2 seconds
        del timers[i]  #delete the timer
        del points[i + 1] #delete the point for the line
```

this gets pretty close after 2 seconds the new line moves to the origin, to fix this, we need to delete the origin point

```
del points[i]
```

but now after the lines disappear, it starts at the last place clicked instead of the origin. so lets check if there is no lines, make sure the origin is the first point

```
if len(points) == 1:
    points[0] = (0,0)
```

Awesome, the last thing is the circles appearing within the 2 seconds, which also means more than 1 line so

```py
if points[0] != (0,0) or len(points) > 2:
    draw.circle(screen,WHITE,points[i],5)
```

Here is the full code:

```py
from pygame import *
import random

init()
size = width, height = 700, 700
screen = display.set_mode(size)
button = 0

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
color = RED
running = True
myClock = time.Clock()

points = [(0,0)]
timers = []

def drawScene():
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    for i in range(1,len(points)): #loop through all but the first point as you dont want circle at origin
        if points[0] != (0,0) or len(points) > 2:
            draw.circle(screen,WHITE,points[i],5)
        draw.line(screen,color,points[i - 1],points[i])

    for i in range(len(timers)-1,-1,-1):
        if time.get_ticks() - timers[i] > 2000: #if been 2 seconds
            del timers[i]  #delete the timer
            del points[i] #delete the point for the line

    if len(points) == 1:
        points[0] = (0,0)

    display.update() #update is the same as flip()

# Game Loop
while running:
    myClock.tick(60)
    drawScene()


    for evnt in event.get():             # checks all events that happen
        if evnt.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if evnt.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            points.append(evnt.pos)
            timers.append(time.get_ticks())
```